# DNS: supporting multiple non-overlapping internal domains

Tags: domain-name-system

Im working on a situation where we have two 'private' domains that need to be handled by different name servers.

Users need to make queries from both domain A and B. The name servers from B do not trust A so I can't refer. (They used to but 'corporate policy has changed'). If the users point to B they won't get the names from A and vv.

Is there a way to 'reject' a particular lookup so it will fall to another domain server? IE If I had ppl point to A for everything except a block of addresses that belong to B - is there a setup that would send these requests back so they would be tried on a secondary server?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "The name servers from B do not trust A so I can't refer" but you could resolve this by using conditional forwarders.

Comment: It used to be that I could forward requests for B addresses from A servers. If I do that now I get the 'external' addresses for B.

Answer (score 2):

Define a zone for B which only forwards to B's nameservers.

```
zone "B.example.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 192.0.2.37; 203.0.113.37; };
};
```

Comment: And like Joe said...in the Windows world this would be a conditional forwarder to the internal DNS server for domain B that hosts the zone for domain B (the private zone).

Comment: Does the nameserver for domain A need to be able to access these servers or just provide the IPs?

Comment: Yes, A's nameserver needs to be able to communicate with the given nameservers, since it forwards the queries to them.

Comment: Dang. That won't be allowed. As far as B is concerned A is in the 'wild west' and can't be trusted.

Comment: If A isn't allowed to talk to B's nameserver, then how can A's users talk to it?

Comment: The (client)subnet(s) in question are internal to B. A is in a different subnet that (until recently) was trusted to make transfers to B. Now A is considered to be external. If I remove A from resolv.conf I can see B internal addrs but not A. Adding A back means no internal B addrs. Does that make any sense?

Comment: In that case, B needs to be forwarding request for A to A's nameservers.